# Generating multiple instances of one opengl object with random coordinates

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Sorry if the question is dumb but my brain just cannot solve it for some reason..

So I've made one opengl object `public static Square ball = new Square(75,75);`

And I am trying to make it so that every so often a new ball appears on the screen

```
public void Loop(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    long timeSinceStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long deltaTime = timeSinceStart - oldTimeSinceStart;
    oldTimeSinceStart = timeSinceStart;
    if(deltaTime >= 15) {
        RandBall(gl);
    }}
```

code for RandBall()

```
   `public void RandBall(GL10 gl) {
     gl.glPushMatrix();
         gl.glTranslatef(rand.nextInt((1280 - 0) + 1) + 0,
                         rand.nextInt((720 - 0) + 1) + 0, 0);
         getBall().draw(gl);
     gl.glPopMatrix();  
}`
```

but when I run the code it draws only one object and constantly changes its coordinates. How do I make it so that it draws multiple objects with different random coordinates? The solution is probably going to be an easy one but I just can't see it :/

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BIT...` every time you enter `loop()`.  You keep erasing the last ball drawn. To see each one you need to redrawn each ball every frame.  Just store the position information created by `RandBall()` in a container such as `ArrayList`. Then after you call `glClear()` loop through the list and draw the ball at each position.